# How to enable 5.0 ghz adapter and select country code?

Tags: usb

I have a generic "RALINK" n 300 adapter.(ebay) Its is working fine in the 2.4 ghz setting. at 130 mbps
The dlink 815 wireless router is capable of working in the 5.0 ghz range.
When I try to enable the adapter to use the 5.0 ghz range it asks me to select a country code from a drop down menu. I am in the USA, I have 1 of 15 country codes which appear as i.e:

## 0: (36-64,149-165)

## 1: (36-140)

## 2: (36-64)

## 3: (52-64, 149-161)

etc..etc
what range should I select?

Answer (score 0):

In the US your looking at a range, per the FCC, between  2.412GHz and 2.462GHz. That's why it's asking you for the country code. If it's working fine in 2.4ghz, as it should, I'd leave it there.